# Regular Expression to match <a> tags without http://

Tags: javascript, html, regex

how to match html "a" tags, only the ones without http, using regular expression?

ie match:

```
blahblah... < a href=\"somthing\" > ...blahblah
```

but not

```
blahblah... < a href=\"http://someting\" > ...blahblah
```

Comment: What language will you be doing this in?

Comment: For the 3.14e50th time... *sigh*

Comment: The best way to match what you're looking for is to not use a regular expression.  Add a few more tools to your belt.  Stop hammering in screws with a bicycle pump.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's more easy to use a [DOMParser](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_parser.asp) and [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/default.asp), not a regex.

See my response in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LBFX8/5/).

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div>
        <a href='index.php'>1. index</a>
        <a href='http://www.bar.com'>2. bar</a>
        <a href='http://www.foo.com'>3. foo</a>        
        <a href='hello.php'>4. hello</a>        
    </div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var type = XPathResult.ANY_TYPE;
    var page = $("body").html();
    var doc = DOMParser().parseFromString(page, "text/xml");
    var xpath = "//a[not(starts-with(@href,'http://'))]";
    var result = doc.evaluate(xpath, doc, null, type, null);

    var node = result.iterateNext();
    while (node) {
        console.log(node); // returns links 1 and 4
        node  = result.iterateNext();        
    }

});
```

**NOTES**

1. I'm using jquery to have a small code, but you can do it without jquery.
2. This code must be adapted to work with ie (I've tested in firefox).

Comment: If you use jQuery, then you might as well use `$("a:not([href^=http://])")` which works in IE.

Answer (score 4):

You should use a XML parser instead of regexes.

---

**On the same topic :**

- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 2):

With jquery, You can do something very simple:

```
links_that_doesnt_start_with_http = $("a:not([href^=http://])")
```

edit: Added the ://

Comment: +1 for an alternative that may do what the OP wants (they were quite vague as to the purpose).

Comment: `<a href="http.html">Nope.</a>

Comment: @Eli The `://` part can be added in easily - the technique is essentially correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = 'Some text with a <a href="http://example.com/">link</a> and an <a href="#anchor">anchor</a>.';
var re = /<a href="(?!http:\/\/)[^"]*">/i;
var match = html.match(re);
// match contains <a href="#anchor">
```

Note: this won't work if you've additional attributes.

Comment: Won't work for `<a href="http.html">` or `<a href="http:foo.html">` (yes, `http:...` does not explicitly imply the HTTP protocol, as all browsers will ignore the "http:" part if there isn't two slashes; `http:/` is equivalent to `/`)

Comment: Updated it to match literally `http://`. Note that browsers (at least Firefox) expands `//example.com/` to `http://example.com/` (or https, depending on the current protocol).

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting your question in that you mean any (mostly) absolute URI with a protocol, and not just HTTP. To add to everyone else's incorrect solutions. You should be doing this check on the href:

```
if (href.slice(0, 2) !== "//" && !/^[\w-]+:\/\//.test(href)) {
    // href is a relative URI without http://
}
```